# Add strong tag only to the elements of a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to find a way in which all the "titolonuovo" classes have the strong tag, not so much for the bold as for an effect that I assigned to the strong tag. Do you know a way with jquery?

```
   <h2 class="titolonuovo"><strong>xxxxxxxxx</strong></h2>
    <h2 class="titolonuovo">yyyyyyyyy</h2>
    <h2 class="titolonuovo">zzzzzzzzz</h2>

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  if (jQuery('h2').hasClass("titolonuovo")) {
//WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaned up the code a little bit too.

It loops through all `<h2>` with the titolonuovo class who don't have a `<strong>` tag as child. Then it uses [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) to wrap the content of the `<h2>` tag with a `<strong>` tag.

If you don't use the `:not(:has("strong"))` it will wrap the first h2 in another `<strong>` tag like this: `<h2 class="titolonuovo"><strong><strong>xxxxxxxxx</strong></strong></h2>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h2.titolonuovo:not(:has("strong"))').wrapInner('<strong></strong>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="titolonuovo"><strong>xxxxxxxxx</strong></h2>
<h2 class="titolonuovo">yyyyyyyyy</h2>
<h2 class="titolonuovo">zzzzzzzzz</h2>
```

Comment: It would be `h2.titolonuovo` I think

Comment: Thank you very much for the help this answer is just what I was looking for, fast and simple, thanks again @DenseCrab

Answer (score 0):

you can just loop through it and check whether class is exists or not.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function()
{
    var h2tags=$('h2');
    $.each(h2tags,function(i,o)
    {
        var currentobj=$(this);
        if (currentobj.hasClass("titolonuovo")) {
            var text= currentobj.text()
            currentobj.html('')
            currentobj.html('<strong>'+text+'</strong>')
            console.log($(this).html())
        }  
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="titolonuovo"><strong>xxxxxxxxx</strong></h2>
<h2 class="titolonuovo">yyyyyyyyy</h2>
<h2 class="titolonuovo">zzzzzzzzz</h2>
```